# Can a Horde be used to classify a sociopolitical group?

Tags: society, geopolitics, tribes

I am trying to do some background research for my world.  I have found a ton of data explaining the hierarchy between septs, clans, and tribes, but above a tribe is where I start falling short on material.

Ideally what I am looking for to create is a group of clans that make up a tribe, that a group of tribes make up a... nation or some regional level entity... which then I hope form a Horde as the overall head of the hierarchy.

This comes to mind when thinking about the game World of Warcraft (WoW) where Horde isn't used to denote a large angry/violent mob destroying all in the way (a horde of zombies, a horde of barbarians, a horde of protesters, etc), but rather a territorial, sociopolitical entity under a war-chieftain.  From there, the various fictional orc groups are broken down into tribes and clans.

**Would the Horde structure system in WoW be acceptable where it goes from tribes to the main Horde group or do I need regional entities to bridge the gap between a Horde and a Tribe?**

To give some background information, I am looking to have the beginnings of each tribe grouping to be regional in parts of the world/map.  Then, One group of tribes/region fight to unite all regional tribe groups into one Horde group.  Think of it like the early days of the Greek Empire where a regional group aka Spartans rose up to unite the other regional Greek states into the Greek Empire.

EDIT: @Raditz_35 provided a link about a Khanate which brought me to a map:

[image]

The term  or a term like Khanate would very much be what I am looking to use in a tribal theme.

EDIT 2:  It seems that a Horde would be on par with a regional grouping according to this wiki about [Ordas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orda_(organization)).  This also goes in line with @AlexP's suggestion to make Horde sub of Khanate.  However, it was also claimed that the [Golden Horde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Horde) eventually broke up into smaller Khanates and contradicts the notion that a Horde is smaller than a Khanate.

Comment: I think you know that, but just to be sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Horde read the section "name"

Comment: @Raditz_35 yes thanks for that! I did see a few articles about the Golden Horde, so it does appear to be historically okay (though this was the only time I found where a Horde was used as a central location).  Would it be okay then to assert that I can have multiple regional groups make up a Horde?  I am also still falling short on an entity between a tribe (city) and a more regional thing (such as a state) then Horde (or nation).  There doesn't seem to be a state term for a group of tribes.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khanate ? The Mongols became a thing once they united multiple regional groups. But I'm no historian. This might get a great answer in a history forum

Comment: @Raditz_35 YES! That actually is exactly what I am looking for.  However, a Khanate doesn't seem to fit the theme in terms of lingo.  Ironically enough though, Khanate actually could be still used as it would play well into my naming scheme of individuals that eventually take over. The term khanate could be given justification through that.  Also found the word Domain but that doesn't have the same feel as khanate.

Comment: "Horde" is a Turkic / Mongol word used for some historical Turkic / Mongol political structures. (And in the names of some modern cities, such as Kyzyl Orda in Kazakhstan.) "Tribe" is a very ill-defined word; Roman [tribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_Assembly), Hebrew [tribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Tribes_of_Israel) and American Indian [tribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribe) are very very different entities. "Clans" and "septs" are highly specific to certain particular cultures. Your hierarchy may exist in a real historical state only by accident.

Comment: @AlexP so it seems you would suggest I study the structure of the Mongol Empire?  How would you break down the term Horde then into sub categories?  Or would you not even use the term horde but rather Empire?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [horde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orda_(organization)) as a Turkic / Mongol organisation. In the Eurasian steppe it is basically the equivalent of an American Indian extended tribe, such as the Apaches or the Cheyenne.

Comment: @AlexP also to keep in mind, I am not looking to mimic the exact structure of a real historical state but rather the validity that my structure is believable.  Clans can make up a tribe under the definition that a clan generally represents a family and a tribe made up of multiple families.  Khanate seems to be the best term to fill in the regional Gap before going to the level of Horde / Empire.  Also thanks for that link!  I do see they reference tribes in that page which also makes me feel better in my usage of the term.

Comment: You may want to reverse the order between Horde and Khanate -- historically a Khanate was (usually) the larger entity. But then, of course, everybody and his neighbour begans calling themselves Khans...

Comment: Wasn't Genghis Khan of Khans? That would mean that khanates are more regional powers.

Comment: @detrivore this is very true and is true according to the map I found of the territories.  A Horde, depending on the way you read it, could very well be a regional entity as well or it could just be a large wandering mass of xxxx.  For my purposes, I want to use a Horde as a regional power which puts that on par with tribes and khanates and still leaves me stuck for what I could consider the national powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because first of all you can define terms for groups in fiction however you want to.

In my opinion, if a question over terminology for fiction requires too much research or arcane study in order to answer, you can just make up whatever you want and arguably call it plausible, because there are very few people who know, and for those who do know, so what--? See my first answer. To care too much about the "plausibility" of elements in a world is to care more about technicalities than the story.

Star Trek throws plausibility out the window every time they go faster than the speed of light, for crying in the mud. At light speed any object of substantial mass gains infinite mass and destroys the universe.

Comment: You make a very good point that if I need to do a lot of digging around, more than likely it won't matter to the general public.  I also understand it is my world and I can do what ever, but I also want it to flow with familiarity so that people aren't spending time having to understand it through context.

Comment: Frankly, as a writer, even if it mattered to a select few, I wouldn't care. They can read other literature that strains "plausibility--" by which I mean they can read *any* literature, and be unhappy with it, if that's their attitude ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I really responded to your comment :p

I'd guess that the noun your after wouldn't be familiar to most folks, but I also expect readers would pick up its meaning easily through context. For example, a leader could order a summons of everyone in the Khanate to battle, and be met with incredulity; and/or as a result, in the story every group shows up; so the readers know Khanate means everyone.

Comment: Not sure the Star Trek comment is physically correct =) But if opinion is the issue here, most fantasy grounds itself using terms and principles that are valid for the real world. This makes fantasy settings easier to "get into", more immersive, because they resonate with the consumer. The opposite is also true - when a principle that is present in the real world is used in a fantasy setting, but it is poorly researched and as a result - grotesquely warped (resonates, then completely wrong the next moment), it becomes difficult to accept, and the immersion is lost.

Comment: When I research it I find some sources interpreting Einstein's relativity as predicting near infinite mass for objects when they approach light speed, and then I find this article which claims that notion is false and that it's more correct to describe it as kinetic energy. :shrug: https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2013/06/18/can-you-go-fast-enough-to-get-enough-mass-to-become-a-black-hole/

Comment: To discuss plausibility of a fantasy world in terms of opinion, I imagine that some readers find errors of real-world similarity very jarring, while other readers don't care at all.

Personally I'm probably more of a mind of not caring about errors of import from reality to fantasy or science fiction.